# MySQL summing and grouping rows for unknown number of IDs by flexible number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot

I have to work with a single table that contains the following columns:

```
COURSE | PROF | SEMESTERID | ENROLLED
```

I never know how many semester IDs will be supplied (at least one for sure).

I have to generate a report, using SQL and MariaDB (current version), that shows a table like this (assuming we want output for semesters ID 1, 2 and 3). Each "semester_x" is the total number of students enrolled for that prof and course.

There are (can be) multiple rows with the same COURSE value for the same PROF and the same SEMESTERID. In other words, the first total of 143 could come from one class of 143 students, or three classes of respectively 100, 20, and 23 students. 143 is the sum of all students for Prof Smith's CPSC 101 course during semester ID 1.

I hope someone can help, because not knowing how to call this kind of aggregation makes it so far impossible to find an answer online. Thanks so much to anyone who knows a solution.

```sql
COURSE   | PROF       | semester_1 | semester_2 | semester_3 | etc.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
CPSC 101 | Prof Smith | 143        | 226        | 129         |
CPSC 101 | Prof Jones | 412        | 387        | 129         |
POLS 234 | Prof Scott | 265        | 176        | 287         |
```

Comment: What you need is called a [tag:pivot]. It's a notorious pain in the xxx neck to do in MySQL.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you! I will look into those.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry , I'll probably have to do that for whatever I can't do in pure SQL.

Comment: Why? Why not do it for all the things you *shouldn't* do in pure sql too?

Comment: @Strawberry - because, and I'm realizing it as I'm replying to you, I apparently hate PHP even more than I dislike SQL. I think I should become a frontend dev, and leave fullstack / backend to others - or switch to fullstack JS, which isn't an option at this time : |

Comment: Well, just FYI, this is a piece of cake in application code, and (as O. Jones mentions) a veritable pain in the neck in SQL (although easier with the most recent versions of MySQL/MariaDB)

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry :-)